# java split 2 dimensional array and convert it into 1 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array.

Let's assume the array is: `int [][] arr = new int [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [20, 11]];`

I need to split above array and convert it into 1 dimensional array.

So, the result must be:

```
int arr[0] = [1, 2]

int arr[1] = [3, 4]

int arr[2] = [5, 6]

int arr[3] = [20, 11]
```

Each of them stands as 1 dimensional array.

How to do that?

Comment: your 2D array iteslf is an array of 1D arrays

Comment: What you want is what you already have

Answer (score 2):

It is already in Java, just like you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use any split. Java already have it as you are thinking. Lets check this example:

```
int [][] arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {20, 11}};
```

Here the `arr[0]` holds the first row, and so on.

Lets print the first column from the first row from the above array:

```
System.out.println(arr[0][0]);
```